# Programmatically center drawable in a layer-list

Tags: android, drawable, xml-drawable, layer-list

I want to generate a layer-list programmatically similar to this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#1e1e1e" />
        <size android:height="45dp"
            android:width="82dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_audio"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Result:

[image]

The main idea is to center the **ic_audio**. To do this programmatically, I tried

> LayerDrawable.setLayerGravity();

But this requires **API >= 23 and my current min is 21**. I can't think of any workaround to get the desired output.

If i remove the

> android:gravity="center"

Result:

[image]

This stretches the **ic_audio** to match the size of the previous layer (at least this is what i think).
Any suggestions or workaround?

Comment: How you are creating it now programmatically ? i.e Stretched version Post that code too

Comment: Currently, I am not creating it programmatically, loading it from xml resource: LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) context.getDrawable(R.drawable.media_art);

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the **[setLayerInset()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable#setLayerInset(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))** like this

```
  LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) context.getDrawable(R.drawable.layer);
  layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1,100,100,100,100);
```

where 1st argument is index of the layer

Comment: Just note: layer first item has index 0